# Cannot upload my app to APP store

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Can someone please enlighten me with the attached issue? I have revoked profiles, downloaded new ones, edited originals, asked Xcode to automatically sign etc I have attempted over 25 times now
I am able to analyse but the below appears as soon as i try to archive and upload.

Thanks-
See attached.

[image]

Comment: Ugh, the $*&#^*)@^ provisioning profiles ... You'd think after a decade Apple would've fixed this mess. XCode's complaining about the App ID, Keychain Access & Beta report functionality, which have to be added as capabilities in XCode, and/or a plist, and/or set in the Dev Portal certificate/provisioning page for a "production/distribution" profile/cert specifically for this app. See the App Distribution Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the couple of things:

1. Double check the bundle identifier. It should match in iTunes App, developer portal and in your app.
2. Remove duplicate provisions (if any) using "iPhone Configuration Utility".
3. Verify the enabled capability from Developer portal as well as from `XCode->Project Properties->Capabilities` Tab.
4. Verify the version number and build number. It should not be the one that is either below or equal to previously submitted app's number.

Hope it helps!